# Python Module Not found error (Requests)

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am relatively new to Python and I was installing a couple of modules - BeautifulSoup and Requests (learning how to scrape). So I installed Requests

```
$ pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2018.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
```

But then I when I run my file, I keep getting this error message

```
$ python test5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
```

Could you help me with why I am having this issue?

On a separate note, all of a sudden BBEdit started asking me when I save a .py file "BBEDIT is trying to install a helper tool" and asking for  a PW. Then it asks again "BBEDIT is trying to make modifications, allow it"? WHy is it doing that? Is it safe?

Thanks everyone and sorry for basic questions

Comment: Your BBEdit question is completely unrelated to your `pip`/`import` question, so you really need to ask it as a separate question (and with different tags, so you attract BBEdit experts).

Answer (score 2):

A Stack Overflow answer can only cover one specific answer, not give a complete tutorial. But you probably actually want a complete tutorial. Also, if you're reading this from the distant future, whatever is written below may be as out-of-date as laptops that only do video and sound without smellovision. So, you should read the [Python Packaging Authority's tutorial on installing packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages).

---

You have (at least) two Python installations:

- A Python 3.6 that you probably installed with a python.org installer, which lives in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/`.
- A Python 2.7 that Apple included as part of the OS, which lives in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`.

If you just run `python`, you get the Apple 2.7, not your 3.6. But you installed your packages for your Python 3.6, not your 2.7.<sup>1</sup> (Plus, you don't want to run 2.7 anyway.)

You're supposed to run `python3`, as explained in [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)—or, better, [use a virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments)—when you have both Python 2.x and Python 3.x on the same system.<sup>2</sup>

Either will solve your problem.

---

If you're curious why `pip` installed for 3.6 instead of 2.7… well, it shouldn't work that way. But Apple's Python 2.7 is a bit out of date (I mean, even out of date for 2.7), so it doesn't even include `pip`. Which means the only `pip` on your system is the 3.6 one. So, even though `python` runs `python2.7` instead of `python3.6`, `pip` runs `pip3.6` instead of `pip2.7`. Which is very confusing, and pretty much unavoidable on current Macs.

This is a part of the reason current recommendations suggest never running `pip` directly; instead, run it like this:

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

That guarantees that the Python installation you're installing `requests` into is the same on that you get when you run your script with `python3 test5.py`.

As things currently stand, as long as you don't ever touch Apple's 2.7, you can get away with just using `pip3`, or even `pip`. But that could easily change in, say, macOS 10.14, so better to get into the right habit.

---

<sub>1. You can tell because of, e.g., the paths in those "Requirement already satisfied" lines.</sub>

<sub>2. Well, the same non-Windows system, but you don't want to learn the different ways in which Windows is messed up, just stick to macOS here…</sub>